# JUnit Assert, Matchers and nested objects

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have the following collection:

```
Set<DecisionGroup> parentDecisionGroups
```

first of all in my test I need to check that this collection contains two objects with a given ids:

```
assertThat(parentDecisionGroups, hasItem(hasProperty("id", equalTo(decisionGroup1.getId()))));
assertThat(parentDecisionGroups, hasItem(hasProperty("id", equalTo(decisionGroup2.getId()))));
```

so far so good...

Right now I need to check that `parentDecisionGroups.get(0).getOwnerDecision()` (where parentDecisionGroup.id == decisionGroup1.getId()) is equals to `decision1` and `parentDecisionGroups.get(1).getOwnerDecision()` (where parentDecisionGroup.id == decisionGroup2.getId()) is equals to `decision2`

how to do this with `org.hamcrest.*` and `org.junit.Assert.*` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CombinableMatcher` to `both(matcher1).and(matcher2)` the matchers.

So you'll get something like:

```
assertThat(parentDecisionGroups, hasItem(
               both(hasProperty("id", equalTo(decisionGroup1.getId()))).
               and(hasProperty("ownerDecision", equalTo("decision1"))));
```