# How to compare lists excluding some items property using Hamcrest?

Tags: java, hamcrest

Trying to compare two lists without considering some filed of elements, but can't find a solution..
How can I write using Hamcrest something like this?

```
assertThat(list, containsInAnyOrder(anotherList).ignoreFields("accountNumber"));
```

Comment: Found [solving this problem using AssertJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565262/9273157), but not Hamcrest

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you want to check if two lists contains equal elements. And to check elements equality you want to compare elements by their fields values.

If so, you might take a look at [equals(Object obj) and hashCode()](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-hashcode-equals-methods/) methods of `Object` class that are supposed to be used to check objects equality - and most libraries and frameworks invoke this methods to check if object "A" and object "B" are equal.

Short answer: First, override `equals(Object obj)` and `hashCode()` methods to check objects equality, or add some custom "comparator" function/class that would compare objects of your type. Then use `containsInAnyOrder(T... items)` or `containsInAnyOrder(Matcher<? super T>... itemMatchers)` methods depending on your choice at first step.

[plum](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/)

Comment: I need to check it using Hamcrest test framework, I don't want to modify list items classes